# Is it possible to use retina images in an input box?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, input, icons, retina

I'm using Bootstrap 3's .img-retina mixin, which has been great so far. For some reason, it isn't rendering the retina quality image in an input box. It's the right size and position, but it isn't retina quality. I'm doing the same thing in a select box and that's working, so the code is set up just fine. I've also swapped out the icon in the input with another (that worked elsewhere), and it came out pixelated as well. Is it just not possible to render the retina image inside of an input?